# how to solve ffmpeg video merging complain about parameters mismatching

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to concatenate an intro video to a main video. Here's my command:

```
ffmpeg -i C:\Temp\intro.mp4 -i C:\Temp\main.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v:0][0:a:0][1:v:0][1:a:0]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[outv][outa]" -map "[outv]" -map "[outa]" C:\Temp\output.mp4
```

When I run this command in cmd, I get the following error:

```
ffmpeg version N-95004-g2f87c9f646 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.2.1 (GCC) 20190918
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
  libavutil      56. 35.100 / 56. 35.100
  libavcodec     58. 58.101 / 58. 58.101
  libavformat    58. 33.100 / 58. 33.100
  libavdevice    58.  9.100 / 58.  9.100
  libavfilter     7. 58.102 /  7. 58.102
  libswscale      5.  6.100 /  5.  6.100
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:\Temp\intro.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41
    creation_time   : 2019-09-21T09:23:34.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:07.32, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 706 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m), 960x540, 323 kb/s, 15 fps, 15 tbr, 30k tbn, 30 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-09-21T09:23:34.000000Z
      handler_name    : ?Mainconcept Video Media Handler
      encoder         : AVC Coding
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 317 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-09-21T09:23:34.000000Z
      handler_name    : #Mainconcept MP4 Sound Media Handler
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:\Temp\main.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
  Duration: 00:00:08.78, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 499 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x640 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], 430 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 11988 tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #1:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 64 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> concat:in0:v0
  Stream #0:1 (aac) -> concat:in0:a0
  Stream #1:0 (h264) -> concat:in1:v0
  Stream #1:1 (aac) -> concat:in1:a0
  concat:out:v0 -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
  concat:out:a0 -> Stream #0:1 (aac)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[Parsed_concat_0 @ 0000018168eedec0] Input link in0:v0 parameters (size 640x640, SAR 1:1) do not match the corresponding output link in0:v0 parameters (960x540, SAR 1:1)
[Parsed_concat_0 @ 0000018168eedec0] Failed to configure output pad on Parsed_concat_0
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #1:0
Conversion failed!
```

I'm not a video ninja. I know parameters are different, but I have no idea after hours of search on how to solve this. A lot of online video services concatenate these two videos and give me a reasonable result. They have a GUI though. I need to do it in code, so that I can automate it.

How can I solve these errors?

**Update:** This is the second error:

```
ffmpeg version N-95004-g2f87c9f646 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.2.1 (GCC) 20190918
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
  libavutil      56. 35.100 / 56. 35.100
  libavcodec     58. 58.101 / 58. 58.101
  libavformat    58. 33.100 / 58. 33.100
  libavdevice    58.  9.100 / 58.  9.100
  libavfilter     7. 58.102 /  7. 58.102
  libswscale      5.  6.100 /  5.  6.100
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:\Temp\intro.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41
    creation_time   : 2019-09-21T09:23:34.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:07.32, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 706 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m), 960x540, 323 kb/s, 15 fps, 15 tbr, 30k tbn, 30 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-09-21T09:23:34.000000Z
      handler_name    : ?Mainconcept Video Media Handler
      encoder         : AVC Coding
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 317 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-09-21T09:23:34.000000Z
      handler_name    : #Mainconcept MP4 Sound Media Handler
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:\Temp\main.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
  Duration: 00:00:08.78, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 499 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x640 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], 430 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 11988 tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #1:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 64 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
File 'C:\Temp\output.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] Y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> scale
  Stream #0:1 (aac) -> concat:in0:a0
  Stream #1:0 (h264) -> concat:in1:v0
  Stream #1:1 (aac) -> concat:in1:a0
  concat:out:v0 -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
  concat:out:a0 -> Stream #0:1 (aac)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[mp4 @ 000002f17869d7c0] Frame rate very high for a muxer not efficiently supporting it.
Please consider specifying a lower framerate, a different muxer or -vsync 2
[libx264 @ 000002f178acfec0] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 000002f178acfec0] MB rate (1600000000) > level limit (16711680)
[libx264 @ 000002f178acfec0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 000002f178acfec0] profile High, level 6.2, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 000002f178acfec0] 264 - core 158 r2984 3759fcb - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2019 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
More than 1000 frames duplicated
Too many packets buffered for output stream 0:0.
[libx264 @ 000002f178acfec0] frame I:1     Avg QP:16.45  size:  4679
[libx264 @ 000002f178acfec0] frame P:32    Avg QP:14.16  size:    33
[libx264 @ 000002f178acfec0] frame B:96    Avg QP:17.67  size:    30
[libx264 @ 000002f178acfec0] consecutive B-frames:  0.8%  0.0%  0.0% 99.2%
[libx264 @ 000002f178acfec0] mb I  I16..4: 58.1% 34.8%  7.1%
[libx264 @ 000002f178acfec0] mb P  I16..4:  0.1%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:99.9%
[libx264 @ 000002f178acfec0] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8:  0.8%  0.0%  0.0%  direct: 0.0%  skip:99.2%  L0: 0.0% L1:100.0% BI: 0.0%
[libx264 @ 000002f178acfec0] 8x8 transform intra:33.8%
[libx264 @ 000002f178acfec0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 4.6% 8.2% 7.3% inter: 0.0% 0.0% 0.0%
[libx264 @ 000002f178acfec0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 74% 22%  5%  0%
[libx264 @ 000002f178acfec0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu:  1% 16% 83%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%
[libx264 @ 000002f178acfec0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 24% 17% 26%  7%  5%  5%  5%  6%  5%
[libx264 @ 000002f178acfec0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 93%  3%  3%  1%
[libx264 @ 000002f178acfec0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 000002f178acfec0] ref P L0: 62.5% 37.5%
[libx264 @ 000002f178acfec0] ref B L1: 99.8%  0.2%
[libx264 @ 000002f178acfec0] kb/s:535069.75
Conversion failed!
```

Answer (score 3):

The concat filter is complaining about the mismatch in resolutions between the two videos. Resize one of them to the size of the other.

Below, I rescale and pad the intro to the size of the main video.

`ffmpeg -i C:\Temp\intro.mp4 -i C:\Temp\main.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v:0]scale=640:640:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=640:640:-1:-1,setsar=1[v0];[v0][0:a:0][1:v:0][1:a:0]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[outv][outa]" -map "[outv]" -map "[outa]" -vsync vfr C:\Temp\output.mp4`

Due to a recent change in the concat filter, `-vsync vfr` is recommended when joining clips with different frame rates.

Comment: Thank you so much. Now it complains that `Too many packets buffered for output stream 0:0.`.

Comment: Again thanks for helping. This time it says `No output pad can be associated to link label 'main'.
Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument`

Comment: Share log for original answer - the one with the buffered packets warning

Comment: Worked like a charm. Can you also explain more in your answer? I mean, syntax is very complex in my eyes and I don't know how to tailor it for other videos I have.

Comment: The first two args to scale and to pad are the width and height of the main video. Rest all, you can keep the same.